# SQL subtracting a value from 2 separate rows, in 2 separate columns

Tags: sql

I am having trouble figuring this out... I am trying to write an SQL query to subtract 2 values from this table:

`RateTable:`

```
RecordID | Policy | Benefit | CBBR  | IBBR 
---------+--------+---------+-------+-------
   1     | 12345  |   A     | $1.34 | $5.64 
   2     | 12345  |   B     | $4.56 | $0.56 
   3     | 12345  |   C     | $5.67 | $3.32 
   4     | 54321  |   A     | $2.57 | $6.24 
   5     | 34512  |   A     | $1.76 | $3.32 
   6     | 34512  |   A     | $4.56 | $1.34
```

I need to create a query that will return the result from the value in CBBR where Policy = 12345 and benefit = A then subtract the value in IBBR where Policy = 12345 and benefit = B ($1.34 - 0.56)

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @suttoa, please show us what have you tried.

Comment: @suttoa, I have added a query that would work in this case, but if you need any generalisations then pls share more information.

Answer (score 0):

As per the details mentioned in query, you need difference between `CBBR` & `IBBR` for particular conditions.

```
SELECT CBBR-
  (SELECT IBBR
   FROM RateTable
   WHERE Policy = 12345
     AND benefit = 'B') AS IBBR
FROM RateTable
WHERE Policy = 12345
  AND benefit = 'A';
```

But if you need generalized query then we probably gonna use `SUM` or something else.

Comment: Adding an explanation to this code sample would help improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am not clear that you want the diff for only 1 value "B" or the pattern will go on if condition (Policy = 12345 and benefit ='A') to get the diff of next row.

ASSUMING diff you want to calculate for all next rows

select *,case when Benefit='A'AND Policy=12345 then CBBR-new_IBBR else CBBR end as diff from(
select *,lead(IBBR,1) over (order by RecordID ASC) as new_IBBR  from <TABLE NAME>)x
```

Answer (score 0):

Ankit Jindal has already gave a correct answeh. However, I'd like to note that there's no need to use any subquery as they can significantly slown down the performance. In this particular case, a JOIN operator is enough:

```sql
SELECT
  rta.CBBR-rtb.IBBR as Result
FROM RateTable as rta
JOIN RateTable as rtb ON rtb.Policy=rta.Policy AND rtb.Benefit='B'
WHERE Policy=12345
  AND Benefit='A'
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question requires more explanation, based on my understanding I think you should use case statement as-

```
Select 
Case when (Policy = 12345 and benefit = A) then CBBR
     When (Policy = 12345 and benefit = B) then CBBR-IBBR
END as Value
From Yourtable
```

Comment: your answer will result in `($4.56 - $0.56)` which is wrong.

Comment: Can you please generalize the behavior of the query you want. like what will happen in case of C and in case of different policy.